# How to pass parameter in request body of restassured api in JAVA?

Tags: java, api, selenium, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
In below example, if i run this it is taking z as string, not as parameter, 

String z=   "1234";
        System.out.println("converted"+z);
        try {
            RestAssured.baseURI = "http://192.189.11.51:05/oceans/fssdata/";
            String requestBody ="{\"CompanyID\":z"
                    + ""
                    + ""
                    + "}";`
```

How to pass parameter Z in company ID, right now it is taking company id as z, I want it should take the value of z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with escaping the quotation marks when using strings directly. You can try using the code below.

```
String z = "\"1234\"";

String requestBody: "{\"name\":"+z+"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONObject to pass the parameter

```
 import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    String z = "1234";
    JSONObject requestParam = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("CompanyID", z);

    given()
            .body(requestParam.toJSONString())
            .post("/your_endpoint");   
}
```

Or you can pass in your way using String

```
"{\"CompanyID\" : \""+z+"\",\n" +
 "\"property\": \"value\"\n" +
"}"
```

Comment: Sir, i tries as you mentioned in 2nd point String requestBody ="{"\"CompanyID\" : \"z\"}"
     + ""
     + ""
     + "}";   getting error as invalid   AssignmentOperator

Comment: I edit the answer for 2nd part, if you want to use multiple rows in JSON String

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

- Maven
  com.github.cliftonlabs

  ```
   import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonObject;
       public void createAnAddress() {
       RestAssured.baseURI = "http://192.189.11.51:05/oceans/fssdata/";
       JsonObject requestParams = new JsonObject();
       requestParams.put("CompanyID", "Monroe Company");


       Response response = given().
               .header("Content-Type", "application/json").body(requestParams)
               .post("/oceans/fssdata/");
       System.out.println("Response Body create Add is =>  " + response.getBody().asString());
   }
  ```